# Is there a difference between "opportunity for", "opportunity of" and "opportunity to"?

Tags: word-choice

Writing a personal statement for an application, I came to the dichotomy of writing "opportunity for", "opportunity of" or "opportunity to". According to my searches, it seems that there is no significant difference between these two forms. However, I wonder if there is any subtle (or even significant) difference in their use in English.

Comment: What is the sentence you wanna use it in? Different types of sentences use a different preposition.

Comment: Are you asking about _of_ vs. _to_ (as in your title) or _of_ vs. _for_ (as in the text)?

Comment: @MorganFR I used it mainly for sentences regarding "being given the opportunity" or "it is a great opportunity". However, my intent with this question is knowing how the meaning of opportunity varies with the preposition regardless of what I am writing.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet Corrected, I mean the three of them.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

***[Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=opportunity%20to%2Copportunity%20for%2Copportunity%20of&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Copportunity%20to%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Copportunity%20for%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Copportunity%20of%3B%2Cc0)***-  ***to*** as a preposition following opportunity is growing in usage, but of and for are also used according to context and usage:

***[Opportunity](http://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/opportunity_1):***

> a time when a particular situation makes it possible to do or achieve something.
>
> - ***Opportunity (to do something)*** You'll have the opportunity to ask any questions at the end.
>     This is the perfect opportunity to make a new start.
> - ***Opportunity (for something/for doing something)*** There was no opportunity for further discussion.
>     There’ll be plenty of opportunity for relaxing once the work is done.
> - ***Opportunity (of doing something)*** At least give him the opportunity of explaining what happened.

OLD

Comment: This does not explains if there is a difference or if it doesn't matter at all. Is there any difference between "This is the perfect opportunity to make a new start.", "This is the perfect opportunity for a new start." or "This is the perfect opportunity of making a new start."?

Comment: @JosuéTonelli-Cueto - no there is no difference in meaning in the sentences you have mentioned, opportunity may be followed by the three preposition. The usage may vary if you have a verb or a noun.

Answer (score 0):

According to Prowriting aid spelling checker, *opportunity to* and *opportunity of* are equally correct with no difference in meaning.